# Letter spacing issue in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

unfortunately I can't reproduce the environment fault in codepen or jsfiddle because first I thought that it could be the css `letter-spacing` property that is messing around, but it's not (here is an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGPNdG) that looks fine in old/new Chrome versions), I think that there are other triggers.

I've found some discussions related(?) somehow to this new version of Chrome acting funny with Wordpress [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/vRbjCc-eafw;context-place=forum/chrome) for example but can't deal with this:

Version 44.0.2403.155 (64-bit)
[image]

Version 45.0.2454.85 m (64-bit)
[image]

Live link [here](http://goo.gl/9plUtt) . 
Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Are you saying it's only in Wordpress?

Comment: Not so sure at this point if this bug(?) is only found in Wordpress. In my case it's, happening indeed in Wordpress, if I open the site page in Chrome 45.0.2454.85 m (64-bit) - please follow the above last live link.

Comment: As a workaround until the bug is confirmed, adding margin-left: -10px solved the problem in v45. Special thanks to [mhodges44](https://goo.gl/bvvR4Z) _but_ using this, in older versions of Chrome (v43, v44) the code will be alterated.

Comment: A New Version 45.0.2454.93 m (64-bit) of Chrome was released; the good news is that the above described bug was fixed :) Thank you Chromium team!