# Chrome 45 Version Position absolute issue

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, kendo-grid

My mvc application has kendo grids and I have used `position:absolute;` for my table's tr:firstChild, td:firstChild to achieve column freezing.
Recently, we have updated to Chrome 45 on our servers and in Chrome, table is coming like <(col1), (blank space), (col2), (col3)> and every other browser (including previous versions of Chrome) is rendering my table in correct format <(col1), (col2), (col3)>.

I am not even able to inspect that blank space in my chrome.

Solutions i have found:

I have written some CSS i.e:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    .tablexyz tbody th:first-child,
    .tablexyz tbody tr:first-child {
        position: relative;
        width: 240px;
        top: auto;
        left: 20px;
    }
}
```

Then I am using jQuery in my pages and setting it manually to absolute and its working fine :

```
$(".tablexyz tbody th:first-child").css({
    position: "absolute",
    width:"240px",
    top:"auto",
    left : "20px"
});
```

What causing the main issue? How can I resolve this using CSS only?

Comment: Typo? **"fisrtchild"**

Comment: yeah its typo sir ...

Comment: If your code was fine in version 44, try to update to the new Version 45.0.2454.93 m. In my case, the bug was fixed :)

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I found the issues, partially, and the possible fixes.

Here's a jsfiddle example setup:

https://jsfiddle.net/j8fr2m1a/

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Alpha</th>
        <th>Beta</th>
        <th>Gamma</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="float:right;">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th style="float:left;">Alpha</th>
        <th>Beta</th>
        <th style="float:left;">Gamma</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="float:right;">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td style="float:right;">3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Alpha</th>
        <th>Beta</th>
        <th>Gamma</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />

<table border="1">
    <tr><th>Alpha</th><th>Beta</th><th>Gamma</th></tr>
    <tr><td style="float:right;">1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Chrome 45's issues with tables are:

If the styles applied to cells in a column are unequal, then the row with additional styling will have phantom cells appear in its layout.

To fix this, either remove the extra styling, apply styling to all cells in a column (the values do not need to be identical), or remove the whitespace surrounding the cells in a table row.

Comment: I have also found that just adding float:inherit to the CSS of a th/td cell, if no float is currently set, will also fix this issue. But all the cells in a column require this.

Comment: Hi Christopher thanks for the reply.But that didn't worked for me either.But from somewhere i seen that replacing whitespace from html will resolve the issue and it did [https://jsfiddle.net/j8fr2m1a/1](https://jsfiddle.net/j8fr2m1a/1) .but in real scenario i am loosing my grid events which was attached before replacing the whitespace :(

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue in Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 m, exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383469/letter-spacing-issue-in-chrome) and I've received an answer - true on other source - from [mhodges44](https://goo.gl/bvvR4Z) (special thanks). At this point, there are more chances to talk about a bug; I am still waiting for a confirmation, I've opened a ticket on Chromium report pages.

Anyway, getting back to your question, as a workaround, try to simply add a `css` negative margin, `margin-left: -10px`. Please let us know if this works in your case too, I suspect something related to `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)` to be responsable for this misbehaviour.

Cheers